# Tight faucet cap

Tags: plumbing, cartridge

I wanted to check the cartridge of my faucet and removed the handle successfully. But, the cap and the part with barbs are so tight. I rotated the spout and rested it against the wall to hold the spout in place as I used a pair of nosed pliers to loosen it (by placing the jaws of my pliers against those barbs) and broke one of its jaws! Here is the picture:

[image: pic of faucet]

Should I use a pipe wrench with a piece of cloth between the jaws of it and the surface of the cap to increase traction? This is the same faucet as in this post:

[Removing the cartridge of a faucet](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/192401/removing-the-cartridge-of-a-faucet/192403#192403)

Comment: Have you tried using a penetrating oil like PB Blaster on the threading that holds the cap on (both at bottom of cap on outside and on inside of cap at top of threading there)? Then you can try the thick rag (not just thin cloth) with a pipe wrench to unscrew the cap.

Comment: It looks like 1 of the 4 ribs/barbs inside is missing, and there is some green corrosion, so perhaps a previous attempt to disassemble ran into similar problems.